# Getting Memory Error in Ansible when using command task in playbook

Tags: ansible

```
- hosts: all 

  ignore_errors: yes

  tasks:
  - name: Install BKUP

    command: yes | var/tocopy/Client/install
```

error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/tmp/ansible_HXcBpN/ansible_modlib.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py",
>   line 2817, in run_command
>       stdout += self._read_from_pipes(rpipes, rfds, cmd.stdout) MemoryError
>
> fatal: []: FAILED! => {
>       "changed": false,
>       "cmd": "yes '|' var/tocopy/Client/install",
>       "invocation": {
>           "module_args": {
>               "_raw_params": "yes | var/tocopy/Client/install",
>               "_uses_shell": false,
>               "chdir": null,
>               "creates": null,
>               "executable": null,
>               "removes": null,
>               "stdin": null,
>               "warn": true
>           }
>       },
>       "msg": "",
>       "rc": 257 } ...ignoring META: ran handlers META: ran handlers

Answer (score 0):

The play

```
command: yes | var/tocopy/Client/install
```

never terminates, when your script `var/tocopy/Client/install` does not terminate, because `yes` as the man page states

> yes - output a string repeatedly until killed

never gets killed. The memory error is a subsequent error, because the output gets somewhere buffered and eats up all your memory.

So use an other `command` that terminates like

```
command: echo y | var/tocopy/Client/install
```

If you need to input the string `y` to your script better use the [expect module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/expect_module.html).